# How to apply jackson's default behaviour in custom serializer?

Tags: jackson-databind

Since Jackson's `hibernate5-module` not working for me. I'm trying to implement my own lazy property filter. I implemented custom annotation introspection successfully.
But when I apply my custom serializer, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is ignored.

```
@Entity
class Call {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "call")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties("call")
  List<CallEvent> events;
}

@Entity
class CallEvent {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Call call;
}

public class LazyValueIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Object findSerializer(Annotated a) {
        var yes = a.hasAnnotation(ManyToOne.class)
            || a.hasAnnotation(Basic.class)
            || a.hasAnnotation(OneToMany.class)
            || a.hasAnnotation(OneToOne.class);
        if (yes) {
            return LazyValueSerializer.class;
        }
        return super.findSerializer(a);
    }
}

public class LazyValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Object value) {
        return value == null || !Hibernate.isInitialized(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeObject(value);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. `LazyValueIntrospector.findSerializer` detects possible lazy properties.
2. `Hibernate.isInitialized` tells me the value is initialized or not.
3. `gen.writeObject(value);` writes if property is initialized.

The problem is `gen.writeObject(value);` method call is ignoring `@JsonIgnoreProperties("call")` annotation.

The question is:
How to apply `@JsonIgnoreProperties("call")` annotation in my custom serializer?

Ps: `spring.jackson.defaultPropertyInclusion=non_empty` property applied globally. Which allows `isEmpty` checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Since the question is how to apply jackson's own behaviors in the custom bean serializer. I found the answer for myself.

1. extend from BeanSerializerBase, not BeanSerializer.
2. override with* methods. Such as `withByNameInclusion` and `withProperties`

This way, Jackson calls appropriate methods when it's needed.

```
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer unwrapper) {
        return new LazyBeanUnwrappingSerializer(this, unwrapper);
    }

    @Override
    protected BeanSerializerBase withProperties(BeanPropertyWriter[] properties, BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties) {
        return new LazyBeanSerializer(this, properties, filteredProperties);
    }

    @Override
    protected BeanSerializerBase withByNameInclusion(Set<String> toIgnore, Set<String> toInclude) {
        return new LazyBeanSerializer(this, toIgnore, toInclude);
    }

    @Override
    public BeanSerializerBase withObjectIdWriter(ObjectIdWriter objectIdWriter) {
        return new LazyBeanSerializer(this, objectIdWriter, _propertyFilterId);
    }

    @Override
    public BeanSerializerBase withFilterId(Object filterId) {
        return new LazyBeanSerializer(this, _objectIdWriter, filterId);
    }

    @Override
    protected BeanSerializerBase asArraySerializer() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Array serializer no supported");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are ignoring only one property, try giving @JsonIgnore over the call property inside the CallEvent entity above Call.

Example:

```
@Entity
  class CallEvent {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnore
  Call call;
}
```

Comment: No, I can't use @JsonIgnore for it. It will ignore completely. No option to unignore for other serialization path.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual example of where `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is ignored it is hard to say. But I think that the custom serializer would need to delegate to the original serializer and not replace it; there's quite a bit more that is needed to support various other features.
To do that you cannot register serializer the way like shown here, but instead replace it using one of methods in `BeanSerializerModifier` (and need to register that modifier with `ObjectMapper`) -- that way you get the "real" serializer to delegate to.

Usually implementations also need to implement `createContextual()` (from `ContextSerializer`) which needs to be passed to the original ("delegate") serializer.

You may want to have a look at how serializers are implemented in Hibernate module itself.